# Chinese garbled occurred in eclipse to android studio

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio

I put in an eclipse import android studio

But the import is completed, all the Chinese become garbled

But I use Notepad (.txt file) to open the correct display

This is how it happened? How to solve?

For example

`接收資料中，請稍候...`(Receive data, please wait ...)

becomes

`±µ¦¬¸ê®Æ¤¤¡A½Ðµy­Ô...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the encoding of Eclipse to `UTF-8`, then import into Android Studio. In Android Studio, the default encoding of both IDE and Project is `UTF-8`, while in Eclipse, if you're using Windows, the default encoding is `GBK`.

Comment: It worked!
I found that Eclipse does not use GBK but the use of X-windows 950 (MS950)
So try a few times more, thank you for helping me!